# Folder permissions

Tags: permissions

I've got this directory structure:

1. Folder1
      1.1 Folder2
      1.1.1 Folder3
      1.1.2 Folder4
      1.1.3 file1

How can I set up special permissions for Folder2 that can not be deleted but the subfolders (Folder3 and 4) and file1 it contains can be read, modify and remove?

Thank you for advance for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

To remove or rename a file, you need write permission to the directory of it. Set the owner to root and change the permission of Folder1 to read only:

```
chown root Folder1
chmod 755 Folder1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the documentation for GNU chmod:

```
RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT

The  restricted  deletion  flag  or  sticky  bit is a single bit, whose
interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it  prevents
unprivileged  users  from  removing or renaming a file in the directory
unless they  own  the  file  or  the  directory;  this  is  called  the
restricted  deletion  flag  for the directory, and is commonly found on
world-writable directories like /tmp.
```

This may be Linux-specific, but you may use `chmod o+rwt` on your
directory to cause its contents to become accessible in the way
described above. This may not be exactly what you want; you do not
mention whether contents should be modifiable by any user, or only the
same one that created them.